# Merge separate flow files with separate JSON together in Nifi

Tags: json, apache-nifi

I am attempting to merge two flowfiles together using MergeContent. The content of both files are JSON objects which I would like to append to each other and wrap both with a JSON key.

File 1:

```json
"Create":[
 {
   "Action": "Create",
   "Book": {
       "Id": "1234"
    }
 },
 {
   "Action": "Create",
   "Video": {
       "Id": 3245
   }
 }
]
```

File 2:

```json
"Update":[
 {
   "Action": "Update",
   "Book": {
       "Id": "5376"
    }
 },
 {
   "Action": "Update",
   "Video": {
       "Id": "8267"
   }
 }
]
```

I need the final output to look like so:

```json
{
  "Transaction": {
    "Action": "Transaction",
    "Type": {
      "Create": [
        {fill in stuff}
      ],
      "Update": [
        {fill in stuff}
      ]      
    }
  }
}
```

What is happening is that my MergeContent processor is picking up more than one flow file out of the Update or Create input and it is merging 'like' flow files together, instead of merging the separate content together.

*Screenshot of my MergeContent* :

[image]

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Correct on the quotes. I have edited that. The curly braces are missing at this stage in my flow for me. I know this is incorrectly formatted JSON but the reason for this is these blocks of JSON get dropped into the Transaction brackets

Answer (score 0):

You can add a **`MergeContent`** processor with

- `Delimiter Strategy` = `Text`
- `Header` = `{`
- `Footer` = `}`
- `Demarcator` = `,`

in order to generate the core part

```json
      "Create": [
        {fill in stuff}
      ],
      "Update": [
        {fill in stuff}
      ]
```

then apply a **`JSONJoltTransform`** with specification

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "#Transaction": "&.Action",
      "@": "Transaction.Type"
    }
  }
]
```

in order to convert them to a formatted JSON value as desired such as

[image]

Comment: This didn't 100% answer my question but it put me on the right path. I originally had two separate flows I was trying to merge together, but looking at your diagram made me realize I could make the Merge a processor group and route both incoming flows into a single Input Port